# Aggregate function that retuns a list in Pandas results in ValueError: Must produce aggregated value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate-functions

I have this `pd.DataFrame`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [2400, 2400, 2400, 2401, 2401],
    'B': [0,1,2,0,1],
    'val': [[], [], [], ['val1', 'val2'], ['val1']],
}).set_index(['A', 'B'])
```

[image]

And I want to group by `A` and then chain all the `val` values in the lists, using this function:

```py
from itertools import chain
def _flattened_set(list_list_elements):
    return list(set(chain.from_iterable(list_list_elements)))

print(_flattened_set([[], [], []]))
>>> []

print(_flattened_set([['val1', 'val2'], ['val1']]))
>>> ['val2', 'val1']
```

So, after the `groupby` I expect this resulting `pd.DataFrame`:

[image]

However, when I do:

```py
df.groupby(level=0).aggregate({'val': _flattened_set})
```

It shows this error:

```
ValueError: Must produce aggregated value
```

Am I missing something? Why it does not work? I have used aggregation functions that returned a list and not an aggregated unique value per se before, but for some reason, this one fails.

Note: I know how to circumvent this issue with more lines of code, but I would like to know why this aggregation fails for this reason

Comment: Cannot reproduce, running your code produces desired result. Pandas `1.3.1`

Comment: [Pandas GroupBy Aggregate Issue #GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24016)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by upgrading pandas to version `1.3.1` as pointed out by [@Andrej Kesely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10035985/andrej-kesely)